# Bottom sheet below toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, bottom-sheet

I have a main Activity with a Drawer Layout and multiple Fragments that I replace on Menu Item click. 
In one of the fragment I'm using Bottom Sheet to display some info. The bottom sheet behavior is working fine : I can switch between different STATES with no problem. The problem is that in EXPANDED state the bottom sheet stays below the activity toolbar even though I set it's Height to match_parent. Here is the XMl (I also would like to implement a collapsing toolbar but I don't know how to override the current one).

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/coordinator"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottomSheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/circle_picture"
            android:src="@mipmap/login_background"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/circle_picture"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@color/buttonLoginColor"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address_bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_below="@id/name_bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/circle_picture"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_create"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/circle_picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floatingButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/buttonLoginColor"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/fab2"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top"/>
```

Do you have any clue on how to set the bottom sheet's height so it matches the full screen ?